# let G be a finite group and let R be a field, show that RG is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

I know this is true because the group ring of the Quaternions Q$_8$ with the reals $\mathbb{R}$ contains zero divisors.  Also, in the case of finite cyclic groups this would also be true.

I know that my general group ring will be the set of sums of the form:

a$_1$g$_1$ + a$_2$g$_2$ + ... + a$_n$g$_n$, where a$_i$ is a field element and g$_i$ is a group element.

To show that the ring of these elements is not an ID requires showing that there are zero divisors in this ring.  Here's what I had in mind:

Since groups are closed under their operations and have inverses, for some composition of non-zero group elements I am forced to get zero.  I know this is probably the direction I should be thinking in, I'm just having a hard time putting it into formal language.

Comment: Hint: Consider the sum of all the elements of the group. What happens when you square this?

Comment: First consider the case of $G$ cyclic.

Comment: Actually, for any torsionfree group $G$, the ring $RG$ has no nontrivial zero divisors. What you have to use is that every finite group has some torsion element (i.e. elements of finite order). Now, let $g$ an element of order $n$, and consider $$(g-1)(g^{n-1} + \dots +g+1) = g^n-1 = 0$$ this shows that $g-1$ is a nontrivial zero divisor of $RG$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Before we begin, let's note that $G$ has to be nontrivial, otherwise the group ring is isomorphic to the field, and *is* an integral domain.)

One good utility to have when working with group rings is this observation:

> If $H$ is a finite subgroup of order $n$ in a group $G$, and we write $s(H)=(\sum_{h\in H} h)$, then $s(H)^2=n\cdot s(H)$ in any group algebra $R[G]$.

Now, the integer $n$ is either a unit of $R$ or a zero divisor depending on its relationship to the characteristic of $R$. This leads to two cases:

- If the integer $n$ is a unit in $R$, then you can divide both sides by $n^2$ to get $(\frac{s(H)}{n})^2=\frac{s(H)}{n}$. That is, $\frac{s(H)}{n}$ is an idempotent.
- Otherwise, there is some integer $m$ such that $m\cdot s(H)^2=m\cdot n\cdot s(H)=0$.

You will see the utility of the first bullet once you prove this: an idempotent element of an integral domain must be $0$ or $1$.

The second one I think you will understand how to use right away.

Now, take a nontrivial subgroup $H$ of your $G$ and apply what lies above. Just make sure you convince yourself why the interesting quantities above are not zero or the identity, and you have a complete proof.

Conveniently, this also extends the conclusion slightly to possibly infinite groups which have a nontrivial finite subgroup.

Comment: Did we have to consider the subgroup H?  Couldn't the same thing work for the sum of all group elements?

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski Yes, but note the last comment which states how this can be helpful for a more general case.

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski Sure, if $G$ is finite and nontrivial, then yes, $G=H$ is a valid choice. But you can get more out of the version I'm talking about.